# Weird crash in NSURLConnectionLoader thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, crash

We started seeing crashes that happen when our app starts.
I wasn't able to reproduce it, and it happens only to a few users.

The exception is: Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS Code: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x3250974659

The crash happened in a thread named com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
when calling `-[NSBlockOperation main]`

This is the stack trace of that thread:

```
0    libobjc.A.dylib     objc_msgSend + 9
1    Foundation      -[NSBlockOperation main] + 200
2    Foundation  -[__NSOperationInternal start] + 840
3    Foundation  -[_NSCFURLProtocolBridgeWithTrampoline processEventQ] + 344
4    Foundation  -[_NSCFURLProtocolBridgeWithTrampoline pushEvent:from:] + 298
5    Foundation  -[_NSCFURLProtocolBridge stop] + 88
6    Foundation  _bridger + 64
7    CFNetwork   __block_global_7 + 24
8    CFNetwork   __block_global_8 + 12
9    CFNetwork   ___performAsync_block_invoke_068 + 18
10   CoreFoundation  CFArrayApplyFunction + 176
11   CFNetwork   RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 74
12   CFNetwork   MultiplexerSource::perform() + 188
13   CoreFoundation  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
14   CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 212
15   CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 646
16   CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
17   CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
18   Foundation  +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 308
19   Foundation  __NSThread__main__ + 972
20   libsystem_c.dylib   _pthread_start + 308
```

Would appreciate any help to understand what's can cause this kind of crash.

Comment: Most probably you are using a deallocated object.

Comment: Did you find out what caused it? I see this on IOS 7 for the first time. Was this related to IOS7 for you?

Comment: Nope, this was in ios6

Answer (score 0):

With me this code indirectly is causing the crash. If I read the crash dump correctly

```
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error]
```

is triggering the NSURLConnectionLoaderThread. This is probably what they use for Asynchronous support. But as I use synchronous request, there is no way I can deallocate an object while the thread is running. If you ask me, that is a bug in IOS 7.

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [self setupRequestWithService:service andMethod:operation];

    [request addValue:CONTENT_TYPE_APPLICATION_JSON forHTTPHeaderField:REQUEST_HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSError* error = nil;
    NSData* jsonData = nil;

    NSAssert(message,@"Message must not be null");

    jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[message toDictionary] options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSAssert(! error, @"Message could not be json serialized");

    Log(@"----------------------------------------------------------------------");
    Log(@"JSON DATA: - %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData
                                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    Log(@"----------------------------------------------------------------------");

    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

    // Send Synchronous Request
    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    error = nil;
    NSData* responseData = nil;
    NSString* responseString = nil;

    responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Comment: We are seeing this same behavior on iOS7. None of our crash reports have said iOS6 and we haven't been able to reproduce it internally. Have you figured this out yet?

Comment: I've seen similar behavior when using synchronous URL requests.  My advice would be to never use them.  They're uncancellable, buggy, they leak a bit of memory for every single request, and they have unexplained zombie issues under the hood.  Better to rewrite your code to use the async methods.  They really aren't much harder to use.

Answer (score -1):

My guess (because without code all answers will be guessing) - is you're deallocating objects you are using in blocks before blocks executes.

Paste a code so we can help more.

Comment: There isn't really code that I can paste, because I don't know which code is causing it. There is not stack trace that is associated to my code.